# How to find past timetables of the French SNCF trains?

Tags: trains, france, sncf, timetables

The website https://www.sncf-connect.com/ of the French railways SNCF can be used to find future trains.

Is there also a way to find past timetables? This can for instance be useful when you are on a delayed train and want to know its theoretical timetable.

Comment: I don't know how to access prior timetables, or even if that info is available. Because trains often repeat on daily or weekly runs, you might also consider looking up next week's same-day schedule for the same-number train you're interested in. I'm planning March/April 2023 travel, and looking up same-day-of-the-week train schedules next week has been useful to learn what runs are usually made.

Comment: What kind of train (TGV, Intercités, OUIGO, regional train…) and when? If you were on a specific train your ticket should show the schedule at least for trains with a reservation (which includes all TGV services). If you train was delayed and it was a TGV or Intercités you can use the [https://garantie30minutes.sncf.com/s/?language=fr](G30) service to get compensation (and at the same time see the official delay).

Answer (score 2):

The [*European Rail Timetable*](https://www.europeanrailtimetable.eu/) and its predecessor the [*Thomas Cook European Timetable*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Thomas_Cook_European_Timetable) contain information about a variety of trains throughout Europe, and, being print books, old editions do not auto-update, so if you can find a copy that was current for the date you are interested in, it will contain the historical information you seek.

Note that not all trains, nor all stations on each line, are included in these timetables, but they are quite comprehensive and usually show all of the most important (and even only slightly important) routes.